# When I call this function, the app crashes and when comment the setImageResource() line, the app did not crash

Tags: java, android

```
public void playAgain(View view)
{
    LinearLayout playAgainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playAgainLayout);
    playAgainLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    activePlayer = 0;
    for (int i=0;i<=8;++i)
    {
        gameState[i]=2;
    }
    GridLayout grid = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);

    for (int i=0;i<=grid.getChildCount();++i)
    {
        ((ImageView) grid.getChildAt(i)).setImageResource(R.drawable.transp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get an Exception? What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to post the exception. Second, The problem is from one of the three sections.

1. The `grid.getChildAt(i)` might be `null`.
2. `grid.getChildAt(i)` might not be an `ImageView` that you are parsing to
3. The address to `(R.drawable.transp)` is wrong

Comment the whole stack trace to find out the problem.